# How to make embed work in command handler in discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I successfully made a command handler with this [guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files)

But some how it doesn't work at all
When I do it without embed it works but not with embed
Rather it logs the error message I added when a command doesn't work
Here are my codes

server-info.js

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'server',
    description: 'Display info about this server.',
    execute(message) {
        // message.channel.send(`Server name:${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Server Info for Bot Test`)
         message.channel.send(embed)
    }
};
```

index.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { prefix, token } = require('./setup.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);  
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        }
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("I have logged in!");
});
client.on('message', message =>{
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

try {
  client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
}
});
client.on('messageDelete', message => {     
message.channel.send(`A message by ${message.author.tag} was deleted, but we don't know by who yet.`);
});
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'general');
    if (!channel) return;
    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}`);
});
client.login(token)
```

This the error I am getting

```
ReferenceError: Discord is not defined
    at Object.execute (/storage/emulated/0/hash/commands/server-info.js:6:23)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/storage/emulated/0/hash/index.js:23:32)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/storage/emulated/0/hash/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/storage/emulated/0/hash/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/storage/emulated/0/hash/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/storage/emulated/0/hash/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/storage/emulated/0/hash/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/storage/emulated/0/hash/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

[a screenshot of when I run the command on discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28qLM.jpg)

Can someone help in fixing this issue ?
I am unable to find the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

to your command file:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'server',
    description: 'Display info about this server.',
    execute(message) {
        // message.channel.send(`Server name:${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Server Info for Bot Test`)
         message.channel.send(embed)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It literally says it there in your code, the "Discord" variable is undefined  in your server-info.js. All you have to do is:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

Put this at the beginning of your server-info.js